# Creating a function that works like "zip"

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to make a function that does something similar to "zip". My problem is that the part

```
a = L4[l:len(L4):len(L)]
```

doesn't work. In the case below, it should take every third element from the L4, and append it to a new list, so I ended up with `[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]`, but that is not really what is happening. Also, it would be even better if I could make tuples, so it would look like `[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]`, but I don't know how to do that...

```
L = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
L4 = []
def my_zip(L):
    l = 0
    for i in L:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            my_zip(i)
        else:
            L4.append(i)
    while l < len(L):
        a = L4[l:len(L4):len(L)]
        l += 1
        L5.append(a)
    return L5
print(my_zip(L))
```

Comment: your function does not know about L4 or L5 since L4 is initiated outside the function scope and not passed inn and L5 is never assigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```py
def zip_copy(*args):
    lst = []
    i = 0
    t = tuple()
    for a in range(len(min(args,key=len))):
        for a in args:
            t+=(a[i],)
        i+=1
        lst +=(t,)
        t = tuple()
    return lst 
print(zip_copy([1,2],[3,4],[3,5])) # [(1, 3, 3), (2, 4, 5)]
print(list(zip([1,2],[3,4],[3,5]))) # [(1, 3, 3), (2, 4, 5)]
# ------------------------------------#
print(zip_copy([1,2])) # [(1,), (2,)]
print(list(zip([1,2]))) # [(1,), (2,)]
# ------------------------------------ #
print(zip_copy("Hello","Hii")) # [('H', 'H'), ('e', 'i'), ('l', 'i')]
print(list(zip("Hello","Hii"))) # [('H', 'H'), ('e', 'i'), ('l', 'i')]
```

Answer (score 1):

For a `list`-like object. Zip "transposes" the list by taking the shortest sublist if terms in sublists have heterogeneous length.

```
def my_zip(l: list) -> list:
    # size of new list
    n_rows_new, n_cols_new = min(map(len, l)), len(l)
    # pairing
    return list(tuple(l[i][j] for i in range(n_rows_new)) for j in range(n_cols_new))
    
L = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9, 9]]

my_zipped_L = my_zip(L)
print(list(zip(*L) == my_zipped_L)
# True
```